# can rworldmap fill maps with patterns instead of colours?

Tags: r, rworldmap

I wonder how to plot patterns in rworldmap? I only found examples that categorized data in colors. What statement should I add to plot in patterns in the below code? Thank you!

```
library(rworldmap)
data(countryExData)

sPDF <- joinCountryData2Map(countryExData
                             , joinCode="ISO3"
                             , nameJoinColumn="ISO3V10")


mapDevice()
mapCountryData(sPDF, nameColumnToPlot='BIODIVERSITY')
```